# FOG Imaging task leaves computer with blank screen

Tags: imaging

My organization uses FOG to image and manage computers in our company. I am trying to image a system with a new image that has been deployed to 20+ systems without a hitch over the past 6 months.

This system has all the original hardware in it, and is the same model as what the image was made on - a Dell Optiplex 760.

I start up the machine, and let it netboot into the FOG menu. I choose to do a `Full Host Registration and Image`, and enter the pertinent information. The image I chose is a `Multi Partition, Single Drive` image, with Windows 7.

My thinking tells me to check for things that have changed. The only thing is that the image was created with FOG 0.33, and I am now using FOG 1.1.2. I have deployed other images made in a similar manner, to different systems, but this one and another model I deployed yesterday are just hanging at a black screen, cursor in the bottom left corner, blinking.

When I log in to the FOG console, it shows the two tasks as being started, but I'm not seeing any progress. These machines were left to image over night, and no change. I even tried restarting the server and trying again, but it shows the same affect.

What can I try next, or how can I troubleshoot where the actual error is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time, I'll know for sure...

My `/var` partition was full! So, the MySQL daemon was not starting. The console was already running on my browser, so I didn't notice that; however, after logging off and back onto the console, I could not actually get into it.

Checking on the server, the `/var` partition was full, and MySQLd was refusing to startup. I cleared up some space, then it let me log in to the console.

The next step was telling the image that it was a Windows 7 image, and `single disk (resizable)`. Then, the computers continued imaging. I'm guessing that the previous systems were working before the partition was filled up.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like FOG is starting the process and then fails on the image which will wipe out the boot sector.  I would image the computer and watch it to see where it fails in it's process, usually watching the machine being imaged will give you a pretty good idea of what's failing.

Since you created the image with FOG 0.33 which used partimage and FOG now uses Partclone you would have had to enable the FOG_FORMAT_FLAG_IN_GUI in General Settings and the set the image to partimage.  If this is the case you would see a this is not a partclone image error.

I'd also recommend upgrading to 1.2.0 as that fixed some remaining minor issues I still had with 1.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see anything running but it is actually imaging in the background. If you wait a while it will finally come up. Also an easy fix is to use your onboard video for the imaging and flip it to the external video card when done. For some reason there is a conflict there. This is what worked for me.